# If Windows is constantly warning me that my notebook battery needs replacing, might it be an OS error?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

[image: Win7 Battery Warning]

32-bit Windows 7 on a Gateway Notebook

What happened is I removed a charged battery to save life and energy while using it plugged in. When I re-installed the battery, Windows suddenly decided it was faulty. It beeps constantly.

Could Windows be right? Is there any way to verify?

Comment: Run diagnostics from bios and check.

Comment: If it’s an error, it’s on the battery’s side. It tracks its own health. Maybe that data got corrupted when you removed it.

Comment: There's a battery test in bios upon booting?

Comment: Do you have diagnostics option in your bios?

Comment: I'll check. Thanks for the pointer.